# Json.Parse in google app script doesn't show object

Tags: google-apps-script

When I try to parse json in google appscript using the following code,  I was expecting  dataAll as an object but the debugger shows dataAll as string and because of this reason, I couldn't parse the json.

```
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(aUrl, getUrlFetchOptions());
var resposnsestring = response.getContentText();
var dataAll = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); 

Here is the data/

{
  "DataSet" : [ {
    "Record" : [ {
      "attributes" : {
        "type" : "Opportunity",
        "url" : "/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Opportunity/006i000000GcJUfAAN"
      },
      "Name" : "EM- Deadul Technology",
      "Amount" : 100.00,
      "AccountId" : "001i000000Q9c8vAAB",
      "Account" : {
        "attributes" : {
          "type" : "Account",
          "url" : "/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Account/001i000000Q9c8vAAB"
        },
        "Name" : "Ellie Mae",
        "Id" : "001i000000Q9c8vAAB"
      },
      "Id" : "006i000000GcJUfAAN"
    }, {
      "attributes" : {
        "type" : "Opportunity",
        "url" : "/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Opportunity/006i000000GcJUDAA3"
      },
      "Name" : "EM- Deadul Technology",
      "Amount" : 100.00,
      "AccountId" : "001i000000Q9c8vAAB",
      "Account" : {
        "attributes" : {
          "type" : "Account",
          "url" : "/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Account/001i000000Q9c8vAAB"
        },
        "Name" : "Ellie Mae",
        "Id" : "001i000000Q9c8vAAB"
      },
      "Id" : "006i000000GcJUDAA3"
    }, {
      "attributes" : {
        "type" : "Opportunity",
        "url" : "/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Opportunity/006i000000GcJUEAA3"
      },
      "Name" : "EM- Deadul Technology",
      "Amount" : 100.00,
      "AccountId" : "001i000000Q9c8vAAB",
      "Account" : {
        "attributes" : {
          "type" : "Account",
          "url" : "/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Account/001i000000Q9c8vAAB"
        },
        "Name" : "Ellie Mae",
        "Id" : "001i000000Q9c8vAAB"
      },
      "Id" : "006i000000GcJUEAA3"
    }, {
      "attributes" : {
        "type" : "Opportunity",
        "url" : "/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Opportunity/006i000000Lpbl0AAB"
      },
      "Name" : "EM- Deadul Technology",
      "Amount" : 100.00,
      "AccountId" : "001i000000Q9c8vAAB",
      "Account" : {
        "attributes" : {
          "type" : "Account",
          "url" : "/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Account/001i000000Q9c8vAAB"
        },
        "Name" : "Ellie Mae",
        "Id" : "001i000000Q9c8vAAB"
      },
      "Id" : "006i000000Lpbl0AAB"
    }, {
      "attributes" : {
        "type" : "Opportunity",
        "url" : "/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Opportunity/006i000000Lpbl1AAB"
      },
      "Name" : "EM- Deadul Technology",
      "Amount" : 100.00,
      "AccountId" : "001i000000Q9c8vAAB",
      "Account" : {
        "attributes" : {
          "type" : "Account",
          "url" : "/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Account/001i000000Q9c8vAAB"
        },
        "Name" : "Ellie Mae",
        "Id" : "001i000000Q9c8vAAB"
      },
      "Id" : "006i000000Lpbl1AAB"
    }, {
      "attributes" : {
        "type" : "Opportunity",
        "url" : "/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Opportunity/006i000000Lpbl2AAB"
      },
      "Name" : "EM- Deadul Technology",
      "Amount" : 100.00,
      "AccountId" : "001i000000Q9c8vAAB",
      "Account" : {
        "attributes" : {
          "type" : "Account",
          "url" : "/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Account/001i000000Q9c8vAAB"
        },
        "Name" : "Ellie Mae",
        "Id" : "001i000000Q9c8vAAB"
      },
      "Id" : "006i000000Lpbl2AAB"
    }, {
      "attributes" : {
        "type" : "Opportunity",
        "url" : "/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Opportunity/006i000000Lpbl3AAB"
      },
      "Name" : "EM- Deadul Technology",
      "Amount" : 100.00,
      "AccountId" : "001i000000Q9c8vAAB",
      "Account" : {
        "attributes" : {
          "type" : "Account",
          "url" : "/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Account/001i000000Q9c8vAAB"
        },
        "Name" : "Ellie Mae",
        "Id" : "001i000000Q9c8vAAB"
      },
      "Id" : "006i000000Lpbl3AAB"
    }, {
      "attributes" : {
        "type" : "Opportunity",
        "url" : "/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Opportunity/006i000000A89SCAAZ"
      },
      "Name" : "EM- Deadul Technology",
      "Amount" : 100.00,
      "AccountId" : "001i000000Q9c8vAAB",
      "Account" : {
        "attributes" : {
          "type" : "Account",
          "url" : "/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Account/001i000000Q9c8vAAB"
        },
        "Name" : "Ellie Mae",
        "Id" : "001i000000Q9c8vAAB"
      },
      "Id" : "006i000000A89SCAAZ"
    } ],
    "ObjectName" : "Opportunity",
    "DataSetName" : "opp"
  }, {
    "Record" : [ {
      "attributes" : {
        "type" : "Account",
        "url" : "/services/data/v31.0/sobjects/Account/001i000000Q9c8vAAB"
      },
      "Name" : "Ellie Mae",
      "Phone" : "(671) 214-5678",
      "Fax" : "(671) 214-5600",
      "Id" : "001i000000Q9c8vAAB"
    } ],
    "ObjectName" : "Account",
    "DataSetName" : "acc"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: Use Logger.log(responsestring); to check if the data is correct. Maybe also use jsonlint.com on that string to verify.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
var dataAll = JSON.parse(resposnsestring);
```

If `JSON.parse()` doesn't return an object, then there is something wrong with how the string is constructed, it's not in JSON format.

Comment: I tried and same result. If I copy the string into online json editor, it shows the output in object form and this means the json data is correct. I also use the same output in a .net program and it works fine.

Comment: Refeekh, did you ever solve this?  I am having a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

The json data I received from the source had escape characters and when I called json.parse, it return a string without the escape char's. I used json.parse again on the new string which returned an object